# Adding DataGridView columns programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, contextmenu

I have a DataGridView filled with productinformation. The datagridview has totally 50 columns but the users don't always need all the columns, I want to help them to be able to choose which columns to show and which ones not to show.

One solution that I would like to programm is that when the user right clicks on the columns they can choose from a list that pops up choose which columns to show and which ones not to shos. Just like the image below.
[image]

How can I do that. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: What is this for?  Asp.net, WPF, WinForms?

Comment: @MikeTeeVee - Its for winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the WinForms ContextMenuStrip and the Visible property of DataGridView columns.

Here is some example code that does what you want:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingList<User> users = new BindingList<User>{
                  new User{Name = "John", Address="Home Street", Title="Mr."},
                  new User{Name = "Sally", Address="Home Street", Title="Mrs."}
            };

            contextMenuStrip1.AutoClose = true;       
            contextMenuStrip1.Closing += new ToolStripDropDownClosingEventHandler(contextMenuStrip1_Closing);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = users;

            dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete);
        }

        void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn gridViewColumn in this.dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
                item.Name = gridViewColumn.Name;
                item.Text = gridViewColumn.Name;
                item.Checked = true;
                item.CheckOnClick = true;
                item.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(item_CheckedChanged);
                contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(item);
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn gridViewColumn in this.dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                gridViewColumn.HeaderCell.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
            }

        }

        void item_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem item = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;

            if (item != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns[item.Name].Visible = item.Checked;
            }
        }

        void contextMenuStrip1_Closing(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

}
```

The User class there is just so the example compiles, providing something to bind my DataGridView to.

I've also added some code that allows users to click more than one column at a time (by checking the close reason on closing and cancelling if it was an item select). This is actually a little borderline in terms of diverting from standard UI behaviour in my opinion - it is usually better to stick with standard behaviour, but I included since it is (I think) useful in this scenario.

Also, it is generally tidier to put this sort of customisation into a new control that inherits from DataGridView.

Comment: @Erika - the datagridview has doubleclick events that you could use. Once you fet this far away from the standard ui though, I'd suggest using some other control, rather then a context menu - you could problably open a modal form on the double click that shows the list of columns.

Comment: @Ekira not sure why that is happening. It doesn't happen in my test code, I'm guessing it is something to do with your existing context menu - perhaps look at taking the context menu creation out of databindingcomplete, or putting a check there to ensure that only new columns are added.

Comment: @Erika what do you mean remember? In my test application this just works on its own within the context menu - if it doesn't for you then some of your code is removing the functionality. Also, the Visible property of the grid columns essentially stores this information. For remembering once the form is closed then you will need some other mechanism, such as a master form that stores a dictionary, or some form of persistance (particularly if you want to close the app and have the selection remembered after)

Comment: @Erika for that you will need to store the list of checked and unchecked columns somewhere other than the form. Where that is really depends on the rest of the application - probably worth another question if you don't ideas of your own. There are numerous places to store user data, but each has its pros and cons that are worthy of detailed discussion.

Comment: @Erika it is just data though - all you need to store is the user id, and the list of checked columns.

Comment: @Erika - have a look at xml serialization - create a class which stores the data you need (the list of checked items and the userid) and then you can serialize it quite easily.

Comment: @Erika you need to apply the logic in your form at somepoint before the grid has been rendered. I believe that DataBindingComplete should be a good place to do it.